# Javascript not functioning when echoed in php

Tags: javascript, php, echo

I'm trying to create a file sharing page for users on a website. Depending on their role they can see different folders. When I wrote everything in html it functioned fine, there are three buttons on the side for each folder but my javascript function hid the ones that were not clicked on. When I put everything in php essentially just echoing it all this stopped working and all the folders were shown. I need to put it in php because I need to show different things for different users. This is the code:

```
echo "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../styles/style.css'>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Dundas Agri Systems Employee Page</h1>
<h2>Always search for a Spirit of Tranquility</h2>
</header>";


echo "<div class='tab'>";
if ($_SESSION["role"]==admin || $_SESSION["role"]==tech || $_SESSION["role"]==emp){
echo "<button class=''tablinks'' onclick=''OpenFolder(event, 'Employee')'' id=''defaultOpen''>Employee</button>";
}
if ($_SESSION["role"]==admin || $_SESSION["role"]==tech){
echo "<button class=''tablinks' onclick=''openFolder(event, 'Lely')''>Lely</button>";
}
if ($_SESSION["role"]==admin){
echo "<button class='tablinks' onclick='openFolder(event, 'Manager')''>Manager</button>";
}
echo "</div>";
if ($_SESSION["role"]==admin || $_SESSION["role"]==tech){
echo "<div id='Lely' class='tabcontent'>
<div id='container'>
<h1>Directory Contents</h1>

<table class='sortable'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Filename</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Size <small>(bytes)</small></th>
      <th>Date Modified</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
";      
openfilesystem('./LelyUploads');   
echo "   
</tbody>
</table>

<div id='Upload'>
    <form action='' method ='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        Select a file to upload:
        <input type='file' name='fileToUpload' id='fileToUpload'>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit' id='submit'>
    </form>
</div>

</div>
</div>";
}
if ($_SESSION["role"]==admin || $_SESSION["role"]==tech || $_SESSION["role"]==emp){   
echo "<div id='Employee' class='tabcontent'>
<div id='container'>

<h1>Directory Contents</h1>

<table class='sortable'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Filename</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Size <small>(bytes)</small></th>
      <th>Date Modified</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
";
openfilesystem('./uploads');    
echo "
</tbody>
</table>

<div id='Upload'>
    <form action='' method ='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        Select a file to upload:
        <input type='file' name='fileToUpload' id='fileToUpload'>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit' id='submit'>
    </form>
</div>

</div>
</div>";
}
if ($_SESSION["role"]==admin){  
echo "<div id='Manager' class='tabcontent'>
<div id='container'>

<h1>Directory Contents</h1>

<table class='sortable'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Filename</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Size <small>(bytes)</small></th>
      <th>Date Modified</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
";
    openfilesystem('./LelyUploads');

echo "
</tbody>
</table>

<div id='Upload'>
    <form action='' method ='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        Select a file to upload:
        <input type='file' name='fileToUpload' id='fileToUpload'>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit' id='submit'>
    </form>
</div>

</div>
</div>";
}


echo "
<script>
function openFolder(evt, cityName) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName('tabcontent');
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = 'none';
}
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks');
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(' active', '');
}
document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = 'block';
evt.currentTarget.className += '' active';
}

// Get the element with id='defaultOpen' and click on it
// document.getElementById('defaultOpen').click();
</script>

</body>
</html>
";
```

The Key is the function OpenFolder which doesn't seem to be getting called properly or maybe not at all. I'm not an expert with PHP by any means so if there's another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do that would be great help as well!

Comment: Do yourself a favor and close and reopen PHP around these massive HTML blocks instead of writing them in echo statements.

Comment: I would do that except that I need the if statements for determining user roles. If the user is an admin for instance certain html blocks should come up.

Comment: You can do `<?php if (blah): ?><html here><?php endif; ?>` It's much easier to read and write.  PHP's alternative syntax is good for templating.  Look it up in the php manual if you want to know more.

Comment: You also seem to have two single quotes together in places `''` change these to double quotes `"` - for example, `class=''tablinks''` should become `class="tablinks"`

Comment: Okay, I didn't know you could do that! Thanks very much, I really didn't like having to echo everything in the first place :D And thanks for the quotes, I had done some recent editing with those quotes and guess I must have missed those. I'll make the edits, and see if it solves my problem.

Comment: Just be careful if you are still piling all that in those `echo` ... to escape double quotes if you have started the echo in double quotes: `echo "stuff <tag class=\"tablinks\">whatever</tag> etc";`

Comment: Yeah, this is going to cause issues trying to call that function: `class=''tablinks' onclick=''openFolder(event, 'Lely')''` .. all those single quotes are mangling the attributes and the javascript onclick attribute.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! I fixed up all the echos to regular html within php tags. And then cleaned up those quotes a bit and it seems to have solved the problem! I also realized I had OpenFolder instead of openFolder on one of my function calls. So glad this got solved, and thanks again for your help!